# Deployment Issue from sandbox to production

Tags: deployment, issue

All,

I am in deep trouble and trying to resolve the issue since last two weeks by my own but seems cannot resolve it.

I have my production up and running and all classes which we uploaded from sand box to production runs fine when I run it from developer console. However, if I try to upload any class from sandbox, there is one particular test class failing with strange error as below

> TestOpportunityQQUpdate    CreateOppQuote  Internal Salesforce Error: 2124338966-175087 (-1070785217) (-1070785217)
>   Stack Trace: null

Here is the code of class and test class

```
public class OpportunityQQUpdate {
    @future
    public static void OpportunityQuickQuote(Set < Id > oppIds) {
        list < Quote_Application__c > QQuoteVar;
        // List to store OpportunityTeamMember to create
        Opportunity lstOpp;
        // Iterate through the list of Opportunities that created from the Lead conversion
        for (Opportunity OppVar: [select Id, OwnerId from Opportunity where Id in: oppIds]) {
            QQuoteVar = [select OwnerId, Contacct_Agent__c, Email__c from Quote_Application__c where OpportunityQuickQuote__c =: OppVar.Id];
            lstOpp = [select OWNERID, Owner.Id, Owner.Name, Owner.Email from Opportunity where Id =: OppVar.Id];
            for (Quote_Application__c Q: QQuoteVar) {
                Q.Contacct_Agent__c = OppVar.OwnerId;
                Q.Email__c = lstOpp.Owner.Email;
                system.debug(lstOpp.Owner.Email);
                Update Q;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestOpportunityQQUpdate {
    static testMethod void CreateOppQuote() {
        /*Lead Ld = new Lead();
        Ld.FirstName = 'Anoop';
        Ld.LastName ='Jain';
        Ld.Status ='Open';
        Ld.Company='gNxt';
        Ld.USDOTNumber__c ='1234567';
        Ld.PAddressCity__c ='Las Vegas';
        Ld.PAddressState__c ='CA';
        Ld.PAddressStreet__c ='ABS';
        Ld.PAddressZip__c ='12345';
        Ld.BAddressState__c ='NV';
        Ld.BAddressCity__c = 'Las Vegas';
        Ld.BAddressStreet__c = 'SBDD';
        Ld.BAddressZip__c ='12345';
        Ld.Title ='12345';
        Ld.Phone ='123-234-1234';
        Insert LD; */
        Account Acct = new Account();
        Acct.Name = 'My Test Account';
        insert Acct;
        Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity();
        // Do you recognize these fields?
        Opp.Name = 'Test';
        Opp.Account = Acct;
        Opp.Amount = 0;
        Opp.CloseDate = System.today();
        Opp.StageName = 'Closed Won';

        insert Opp;
        Quote_Application__c QQ = new Quote_Application__c();
        //  QQ.Leads__c = LD.Id;

        QQ.OpportunityQuickQuote__c = Opp.Id;
        QQ.InsuredBusinessName__c = 'gNxt';
        QQ.No_Email__c = true;
        QQ.Mailingaddress__c = 'abdc';
        QQ.MailingCity__c = 'Las Vegas';
        QQ.Mailing_State__c = 'CA';
        QQ.MailingZip__c = '12345';
        QQ.PrincipleOwnerName__c = 'Anoop';
        QQ.Social_Security__c = '519-50-1234';
        QQ.EIN__c = '43-6433434';
        QQ.DOB__c = Date.today();
        QQ.BusinessStartedYear__c = Date.today();
        QQ.Drivers_License__c = '1222';
        //   setConvertedOppIds.add(Opp.Id);  

        QQ.Drivers_License_State__c = 'CA';
        QQ.InsuredPhoneNo__c = '123-234-1234';
        Insert QQ;
        id qqid = qq.ID;
        Commodities_transported__c CD = new Commodities_transported__c();
        CD.Avg_Value__c = 100;
        CD.Cargo_Info__c = 'AVG';
        CD.Freight_percent__c = 1;
        CD.Quote_Application__c = QQ.Id;
        Insert CD;

        Garage__c GR = new Garage__c();
        GR.City__c = 'New York';
        GR.State__c = 'CA';
        GR.Street__c = 'Test';
        GR.QuoteApplication__c = QQ.Id;
        GR.Zip__c = '12345';
        Insert GR;

        Driver__c DR = new Driver__c();
        DR.Accidents__c = '1';
        DR.CDL_Year__c = Date.Today();
        DR.DateOfHire__c = Date.Today();
        DR.Quote_Application__c = QQ.Id;
        DR.License__c = '12345';
        DR.Name_del__c = 'test1';
        DR.Type__c = 'Employee Driver';
        DR.Violations__c = '1';
        DR.DOB__c = Date.Today();
        DR.State__c = 'CA';
        Insert DR;

        Vehicle__c VR = new Vehicle__c();
        VR.CurrentValue__c = 100;
        VR.Deductable__c = '1000';
        VR.GVWR__c = 'Test';
        VR.Quote_Application__c = QQ.Id;
        VR.Make_Model__c = '12345';
        VR.Radius__c = '25';
        VR.Type__c = 'Tractor';
        VR.VIN__c = '1222222';
        VR.Year__c = '1989';

        Insert VR;

        Quote_Application__c QQAfter = new Quote_Application__c();

        QQAfter = [select CTCount__c from Quote_Application__c where id =: qqid];

        system.assertequals(QQAfter.CTCount__c, 1);

        /* Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
                lc.setLeadId(Ld.id);
                lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
                lc.setConvertedStatus('Qualified');
                Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            */

        /*  QQ.OpportunityQuickQuote__c =lcr.getOpportunityId();
          UPDATE QQ;*/
        Set < Id > setConvertedOppIds = new Set < Id > ();
        setConvertedOppIds.add(opp.Id);
        OpportunityQQUpdate.OpportunityQuickQuote(setConvertedOppIds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bug to me as Error Message includes stacktrace ID. I would request you to log a case with Salesforce and they will check whether the issue related to Summer'16 release or any bug.

Comment: Thanks Shanu since we are not having premier support, we cannot log the case with Salesforce but I am very sure that this is the case

Comment: @anoopjain for stack trace ID you can log a case with basic support

Comment: Thanks and I worked with Salesforce support team yesterday and there solution worked like a charm. they have asked to do the below as it is a known issue

Turn off "Enable User Control over Task Assignment Notifications" (Customize>> Activities>> Activities Settings) and try to deploy again.